# How can I check if a primary key value exists in another table or not?

Tags: laravel, exists

I have id(Primary key) of `country` in multiple tables and I want to check if its value exists or not in another referenced table.

Tried using the below code but I don't think this is the right way. Can anyone please suggest something...

```
public function check($id)
{
    $state = State::pluck('country_id');
    $country = DB::select("select count(*) from country where ? not in (?)",[$id,$state]);

    if($country == 0)
    {
        //
    }
    else{
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if a relationship for a record is present (or exists), using `exists`.

Assuming you have a relationship on your `Country` model called `states`:

```
public function states
{
  return $this->hasMany(State::class);
}
```

You can check if a `Country` has any `States` related to it in your database.

```
// returns true if there are related states, otherwise false
Country::first()->states()->exists();
```

You can use whatever filtering criteria you want, so rather than `first()` you could use `find($id)` or `where('field', $value)` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Exists](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#determining-if-records-exist) Method here

```
public function check($id)
{
    $state = State::pluck('country_id');
    $country = DB::table('country') //table set
       ->whereIn('column_name',$state) //if array then used whereIn method
       ->where('column_name',$id) //if single value use where method
       ->exists();         

    if($country)
    {
        //
    }
    else{
        //
    }
}
```